# How to cut a Fano plane and get a Mobius strip

Tags: general-topology

Considering that the Fano plane is a finite projective plane, how can you cut it so as to get its constitutive mobius strip?

Comment: The real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ contains a Mobius strip. So does every nonorientable surface - and topological surfaces are spaces that are locally homemorphic to open subsets of $\Bbb R^2$. Is there a definition of "Mobius strip" that allows finite projective planes to have them? Like, "Mobius ladders," or something? Googling "Mobius strip finite projective planes" yields no meaningful results on the first page (indeed, this very question appears on it!)